# Intuitions for ker of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some linear algebra ta for the first time, and while I can solve exercises and read through proofs and definition, I would like to offer my student some extra intuition...which I lack.

I'm currently reading about vector spaces and linear map and would like to find some intuition for the kernel of a linear map. I understand the definition, the kernel is a subset of vectors for which the map returns the zero vector of the target space.

What I would like is either:

- an example where there is some geometric intuition to get
- an example of how the concept itself can be used (e.g. In a proof)

Comment: Kernel is orthogonal to row space

Comment: The first/fundamental isomorphism theorem

Comment: Fix integers $k,m,n$ with $k$ the smallest, and consider the linear map from $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m $ defined by $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_k,0,\dots,0)$. The image corresponds to the first $k$ coordinates in the codomain, while the kernel corresponds to coordinates $k+1$ through $n$ in the domain. The point is, if suitable bases are chosen for the domain and codomain of a linear map $T\colon V\to W$, then *every* linear map looks like this. The kernel is just a way of codifying this phenomenon without needing to change bases.

Comment: Greg this was brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My opinion –– which is biased probably –– is that the kernel is best understood geometrically using the standard projection map $\pi:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}$ given by $\pi(x,y)=x$. Then we can think of the fibre $\pi^{-1}(0)=\ker \pi$. You can also see that all of the elements of $\Bbb{R}^2$ are translates in the $x$ direction of an element of the fibre. Thinking of examples of this type in higher dimensions motivate the rank-nullity theorem also. Indeed, in this case it's quite clear that $\dim \ker \pi+\dim \operatorname{ran} \pi=\dim \Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: This is a good example, but I get even more mileage from an R^3 to R^2 projection. This is the familiar projection from a real world city to a road map of that city. We note that the top floor of a building and the basement of that building appear in the same place on that map.

Comment: Then, you can follow it up with the map from points in the city (and its airspace) to altimeter readings. Now the kernel is a plane, and the range is a line. Rank-nullity: 3=1+2, or in the previous, 3=2+1.